# insert multiplo ao banco de dados php

Tags: php, mysql

Ola estou criando um encurtador de link e queria colocar um insert multiplos de link tipo a pessoa coloca varios links em um input separando cada link com % ou outro caractere e cada fez q o php ler o % ele da um insert novo ja tentei varias coisas mas n conseguir alguem pode me ajudar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tentou com a função explode?

```
<?php
$campo = "link1%link2%link3";
$retorno= explode("%", $campo);
 echo $retorno[0]"<br>".$retorno[1]"<br>".$retorno[2];
?>

A string ira retornar o seguinte valor:
link1
link2
link3
```

Comment: n lembrava desse comando muito obg